# LibGDX ImageButton image not to scale?

Tags: java, resize, libgdx, imagebutton

[image: screenshot of image]

The red square is the button's boundary, while the image remains centered at 32x32px. I've tried using button.getImage() to set position and size to the button's values, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Not quite an answer, but something I found: setting setMinWidth() and setMinHeight() on the button's style's drawables sets the image to the button's boundaries, but does not scale properly, as seen [here](http://i.imgur.com/tmwwbvI.png).

Comment: Facing the same problem

Answer (score 5):

Just use a regular `Button`. It also contains a `Drawable` for its background, but that one is always stretched to fill the button. See the [JavaDoc for `ImageButton`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.html):

> ... If the image is the size of the button, a Button without any children can be used, where the `Button.ButtonStyle.up`, `Button.ButtonStyle.down`, and `Button.ButtonStyle.checked` nine patches define the image.

Note that these don't actually need to be nine patches; any `Drawable` will do.

Comment: I just switched from ImageButton to Button and it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Probably super late but have you tried:

```
yourButton.getImage().setFillParent(true);
```

Comment: It resizes the image, but then it is no longer centered in the button

Comment: I figured out how to set the sizes and wrote an answer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Extending on the answer of @xitnesscomplex: 
 You can use `yourButton.getImage().setFillParent(true);` to set the size.

To set an offset is somewhat counter-intuitive

```java
ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
style.imageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(btn.png")));
ImageButton yourButton = new ImageButton(style);
style.unpressedOffsetX = -new_brush.getWidth()/4.0f;
style.unpressedOffsetY = -new_brush.getHeight()/4.0f;
style.pressedOffsetX = -new_brush.getWidth()/4.0f;
style.pressedOffsetY = -new_brush.getHeight()/4.0f;
style.checkedOffsetX = -new_brush.getWidth()/4.0f;
style.checkedOffsetY = -new_brush.getHeight()/4.0f;
yourButton.getImage().setFillParent(true);
```